# dynamic checkboxlist to be selected and passed the value of selected item on button click

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a checkboxlist and dynamically it displays value of the list.
But I need to design as per the image shown. What css class or which option to be used to achieve this.

[image: Sample]

```
listcontents.Add(thisQ.Option.ToString());
//CheckBoxList CB = new CheckBoxList();
CheckBoxList1.DataSource = listcontents;
CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Why you think, that this code can help us to see what is your problem?

Comment: Hey, you an refer this bootstrap link for custom css of checkboxlist.

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#checkmark-on-selected-option

Comment: @SeM-ՍեՄ What Code I can give , I can only give the list options code.AS with the styling I am stuck ,hence I have posted here. you should have understood the things based on the question and Image.Instead you are commenting something irrelevant to the question at all.If you have any solution provide ,else ignore the post and move on. You don't need to question me back.

Comment: @ManpreetMatharu Thanks for the suggestion. It only shows dropdown values. I want something like the one mentioned in the image in the question